# Application does not exit on logout

Tags: c++, linux, qt, signals

I would like to ask what is the signal that is called when the user logs out? I have a Qt gui app that has handler for `SIGTERM` and `SIGHUP` signals. The app also has its own close event handler, so user can't close it by clicking on "X". The problem is that when the user logs out then the ubuntu hangs (the icon from taskbar disappears but the process keeps running) and does not let the user log out because (imo) it waits for the process to be terminated. When I use `kill -15 'myapp'` command then the app closes normally as it is supposed to so the problem shouldn't be in my handler.

```
static int setupHandlers(){
    struct sigaction hup,term;

    hup.sa_handler = signalHandler;
    sigemptyset(&hup.sa_mask);
    hup.sa_flags = 0;

    if (sigaction(SIGHUP, &hup, 0) > 0){
       return 1;
    }

    term.sa_handler = signalHandler;
    sigemptyset(&term.sa_mask);

    if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &term, 0) > 0){
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`signalHandler` just calls `exit(0)` (also tried `_exit(0)` and `abort()`)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 standart terminating signals, that you can handle - SIGINT, SIGQUIT and SIGTERM. Try to subscribe to each one of them and look.

Comment: Oh, and you forgot to add signals to set: `sigaddset(&hup.sa_mask, SIGHUP)`

Comment: Nothing changed, it still won't let me to log out.

Answer (score 0):

> signalHandler just calls exit(0) (also tried _exit(0) and abort())

You rather need to tell Qt to exit. Your signal handler need to have a reference on the application object and call `QCoreApplication::exit(0);`.

Whether it is by SIGTERM or by the user user input, your application need to nicely handle termination requests. In particular ensure that all objects which launch a process or a thread are cleanly destroyed when it happens. The classic code inspired from [QtCreator](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/source/619e52ebc2e47e3a024c1df57a772e35b2bb6943:src/plugins/projectexplorer/applicationlauncher.cpp#178) :

```
    d->m_guiProcess.terminate();
    if (!d->m_guiProcess.waitForFinished(1000)) { // This is blocking, so be fast.
        d->m_guiProcess.kill();
        d->m_guiProcess.waitForFinished();
    }
```

The code executing this need to stop, so it first forward nicely a `SIGTERM` (terminate), wait for small amount of time and then ask rudely with a `SIGKILL` (kill).